# Error: TranformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:org/apache/http/HttpMessage.class error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In Android studio,for my preliminary test for my app, i build it. After gradle build success, when it is made to run, it throws an error,

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/HttpMessage.class
```

my app:build.gradle file is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.nxtgn.jaunt"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.9.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.3.jar')
compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar')
}
```

its hard for me to figure out my mistake. Please help me where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal you need to execute in root project folder

```
./gradlew clean
```

Comment: don't forget to Build/Clean Project from Android Studio Menu

Comment: i did both in terminal and also in android studio, but still when it is made to run, it results in the same error

Comment: remove    :                                                                                            
compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar') and 
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.3.jar')
and use   compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
instead